# Xubuntu20.04 - Xfce4 Panel disappeared, can't add Wifi Icon to new one

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, xfce, xfce-panel

When I've restarted my Xubuntu20.04 then my panel disappeared and I had a new empty one. Ok, so I wanted to configure the new one and when was adding the items to it I couldn't find the one that shows Network Wifi (Wifi Icon), I googled and seems that adding Indicator plugin should solve problem but when I add it, it's just empty.

Is there a way to bring up the panel like after installation of OS what to do to have that Wifi Icon?

**SOLVED**
*Needed to add to Panel: Status Notifier Plugin*

Comment: The problem is not with the panel, but with the device. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Wifi works have no a problem with it. Anyway I've edited and put the output of the command you've sugested.

Comment: Hey Ziggy, you could add your solution as an answer and accept it yourself! It is always easier to find the solutions this way :) (I've posted an answer myself, but yours was instrumental to finding my fix, so I'd really like to upvote your answer.)

Comment: @brandizzi
Look up the first post: I've explain how I've solved it next to: SOLVED

Comment: Yeah, I know, and it helped me a lot! It is just that, in Stack Exchange sites, we are used to adding the answers as answers. It is the "best practice" here, so to say, and people can and should answer their own questions, accepting the answers they posted themselves. But no worries, it was just a suggestion, and thank you for your help!

Comment: @brandizzi I was few times down voted when answered my question even with solution and was told to Edit :-) It was on StacOverflow perhaps here you've different rules.

Comment: Wow, whoever did it is dead wrong! Stack Exchange sites in general (and Stack Overflow in special) have very explicit rules to accept self-answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer, https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question, https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer. Just point one of these links next time someone bothers you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after updating to Ubuntu 20.04. As the OP mentioned, the solution was to add the *Status Notifier Plugin* back to the panel.

In my case, however, the plugin was uninstalled at some point, so I had to install it back:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xfce4-statusnotifier-plugin
```

Fortunately, after APT was done, I could add it back to my panel.